# NSTimer doesn't work in a NSThread?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsthread

a very simple using of NSThread and NSTimer like below. When the user clicks a button, I want @"aaaaa" to be printed each second, but @"aaaaa" is being printed only once? Seems NSTimer doesn't work...help

```
//this method is connected to 'run' button in IB
- (IBAction)begin1:(id)sender {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(thread1) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)thread1{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(aaa)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

-(void)aaa{
    NSLog(@"aaaaa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not retaining the timer. `+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats` returns an autoreleased NSTimer, so you should retain it somewhere if you want to make sure it runs until you tell it to stop.

Comment: thank you. seems I've also missed the 'NSRunLoop' around creating NSTimer.

Comment: why does he need to retain it? He doesn't use it in another function and it should be workable. Or do you use ARC?

Answer (score 0):

To a run loop, the timer is not a valid source which will keep it running. Presumably, your run loop sees it has nothing to do then exits, invalidating its timer -- that will be the case if your actual implementation is as is written. So, you will need to make sure the run loop of the secondary thread continues in order for the the timer to keep firing, because the thread just exits and takes the timer with it now.